# Android | Tabactivity slide to other page programmatically

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, tabactivity

I have an tabbed activity. At the moment with 3 pages. My plan is, when I press a button, or do another action, that it slides to another page. But it should do it with an animation, not "jump" to the other page. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you have set up your activity and its tabs. If you are using a `ViewPager`, [use `setCurrentItem(position, true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)) to smoothly scroll to a new `position`.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, I use ViewPager. And it works. But can I set a duration for the animation?

Comment: I suspect that you can, but I am not certain of the technique. I'd start with `setPageTransformer()`.